# Powershell editor with intellisense that I can embed into my program?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise, powershell-sdk

I have a C# application and want to allow people to write powershell code within my app.

Does anyone know of a powershell editor with intellisense that fits the bill??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PowerGUI is the choice here. Check out http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/ and see how PowerGUI is used within Visual Studio.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks ravikanth!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out PowerSE (http://www.powerse.com), it's free.  But, there is also an OEM version, which allows you to hook in the editor to edit/debug the PowerShell commands.  then get the command text back for storing and executing within the context of your application.